# Automated testing of AEM Workflows

Tags: testing, automated-tests, workflow, aem

Is there a way I can automate testing of Adobe AEM workflows?

I've looked at [Hobbes.js](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/test-api/index.html) but there's no mention of workflows as far as I can see. This would be ideal if it handled workflows across multiple users.

I think this might be too challenging for Cucumber and arduous to get working reliably. I've also considered [Prosper](https://github.com/OlsonDigital/prosper) but that's essentially mock framework.

Answer (score 3):

Testing workflows can be tricky but it's possible. If you think about it, it's not much different from testing any other web application. You just need a way to control the browser, switch between accounts and manage potentially complex test scenarios in a comprehensible way.

Another key requirement that in my opinion is the main problem with Hobbes is that the test code needs to be possible to execute easily from a command line and generate useful reports for later consumption. Without this, it's difficult to integrate such tests into any automated pipeline on a CI server.

My current project team has had some success testing customized approval and replication workflows. The tests took a lot of time to write compared to the time we spent actually cusomizing the workflows but the tests are stable.

Our approach relies on browser-based testing of the Author instance using a combination of Selenium Web Driver Java (for browser control), Google Guice (for managing complex graphs of page objects and various utility functions) and JUnit/Cucumber for the control of test scenarios.

One of the key challenges is that the WYSIWYG AEM authoring interface tends not to behave very reliably in terms of how quickly it loads. There's a lot of dynamic parts, some of which are based on ajax calls.

The task is especially difficult if you use Classic UI with its ExtJS front-end and many, many iframes. With Touch UI, targeting the right elements of the interface is a lot easier in my opinion.

That said, you'll have to put quite a lot of effort into figuring out the quirks of these interfaces before you're able to write test code efficiently.

The company I work for noticed that and based on our experience with numerous AEM projects, we put together a framework that takes one's mind off most of the boilerplate code. It provides interfaces for interacting with key elements of the AEM UI out of the box.

We open-sourced it under the Apache 2.0 License. It's called *Bobcat*. Feel free to check out [the project's Github page](https://github.com/Cognifide/bobcat) and have a look at a [simple example project](https://github.com/Cognifide/bobcat/wiki/AEM-Login).

Bobcat has also been adopted outside of Cognifide. This [blog by *liatrio*](https://liatrio.com/bobcat-aem-ui-testing-framework/) contains a nice summary of the features they found especially useful.